# React Native - position "absolute" not working in Android

Tags: android, react-native

Somehow `position: 'absolute'` is not working in Android. It's working with iOS, but in Android it's not rendering. Does anybody know how to set position: "absolute" on an Android device?

```
Button: {
  position: "absolute",
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  borderRadius: 4,
  borderWidth: 2,
  width: 100,
  height: 40,
  borderColor: 'red',
  backgroundColor: "rgb(72, 120, 166)",
}
```

Comment: Did you try rapping the button into a view?

Comment: If it's not rendering, it might be outside of the parent container. `overflow` on Android is always `'hidden'` - `'overflow: visible'` does not work

Comment: i am getting same issue

Answer (score 14):

Wrapping the Button inside a View will work for both Android & iOS:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonView}>
        <Button style={styles.button} title={"Click"}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  buttonView: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 0,
    top: 0
  },
  button:{
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'red',
    backgroundColor: "rgb(72, 120, 166)",
  }
});
```

Comment: This did not work.
``` <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ paddingTop: 50, marginLeft: 30, position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 20 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => history.push('/menu')}>
                        <GHIconMenu style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a **textinput** in your screen, you should check the windowsoftinputmode in 
 AndroidManifest.xml. if it's **adjustResize**, you should change it by **adjustPan**

your's:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

should be:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work fine on Android (not sure for IOS)

```
 <View style={styles.containerView}>
      {/* SearchBar */}
        <Animated.View style={{
          transform: [{ translateY: translateSearchContainer }], 
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.sans,
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
          height: 60,
          elevation: 4,
          zIndex: 100,
        }}>
        <AvoidKeyboard>
          <TextInput
            ref={textInputRef}
            placeholder="Paket Hidroponik Pemula"
            clearButtonMode="always"
            value={word}
            onChangeText={(value) => setWord(value)}
            style={styles.input}
            onFocus={() => onTextInputFocus()}
            onBlur={() => onTextInputBlur()}
            clearTextOnFocus
          />
        </AvoidKeyboard>
        <IconButton icon="bell-outline" color={COLORS.white} onPress={() => onPressBell()} />
      </Animated.View>
</View>
```

and this my styles

```
containerView: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
  input: {
    // flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    width: 270,
    backgroundColor: '#e4e6eb',
    borderRadius: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 30,
    // fontSize: 15
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I noticed that if I add a border the issue was fixed. So I solved it by adding this:

```
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    ${Platform.OS === 'android' &&
    css`
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        margin: -1px;
    `}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"100%"`.

if you are trying to center it at the bottom add `bottom:"100%"`

if top then `top:"100%"` which is exactly like the number 0, and this should work on all Platforms.